# Some Problems facing me in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

I downloaded a rig file when i was using blender 2.79 and worked perfectly with rendering , texturing and so son

but after i uninstall 2.79 and start to use version 2.8, faced some problems

1)The rig is not textured (even in rednered mode) anymore when i open it with 2.8
2)When I texture the rig and render, it doesnt look like what was rendered in 2.79 original file It just looks like texture itself rendered

[image: in 2.79 it looked like this]
in 2.79 it looked like this

[image: in 2.8 it looks like this]
in 2.8 it looks like this

Any solution....? plz

Comment: when you're talking about the rig I guess you're talking about the mesh, but in 2.8 it looks like it's still textured, it looks more like it lacks some lightings?

Comment: Could it be that you used add-ons that were installed on 2.79b that were required to get this scene working? Are there any errors displayed on the console?